Internal Sharing shoes this version of app may be old but the target SDK of my app is set to 35
I am facing this weird issue with Google Play Internal App Sharing. When anyone with the internal app sharing link tries to install the app, it shows a message saying "This version of this app (85) may be old. Turn off auto-update for this app to keep it from getting updated". The current build set up for internal testing has the target SDK set to 35 and the version code is also set to the latest. The app is not installed on my device, and I have made sure that it is uninstalled.

It means the live production version is ahead of the internal version. What is the version code of the live version?

Live Production version is 84, internal version is 85
